# Plotly funnel chart in R

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I am trying to put a funnel chart in my shiny dashboard.
I am using plotly but type "funnel" seems not to be available as option.
I have already update my R and Plotly package, but the problem stays. 
Did any of you try something similar?
Here the code I used:

```
plot_ly(
    type = "funnel",
    y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"),
    x = c(39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2))
```

Comment: Funnel plots are not yet available for the CRAN version of plotly. Please see [this](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1623#issuecomment-534123675). You'll need to use `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`.

Comment: Thank you, I have already tried but It still doesn't work. Here the error I get: "Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  (converted from warning) InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Tempo esaurito per l'operazione'
Error: Failed to install 'plotly' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) download of package ‘BH’ failed"

Comment: You should re-check you installation - your code works fine for me using plotly_4.9.0.9000 - see `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Yes, that's the problem: I have difficulty installing the right version of plotly.

Comment: Here the error: WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools custom from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/plotly@master
Installing 1 packages: BH
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/4931934/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/BH_1.69.0-1.zip'

Comment: Well, I'd start installing Rtools.

Comment: As you suggest, I installed Rtools but I think the problem is here: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/BH_1.69.0-1.zip.

Comment: The error I get now: Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/plotly@master
Installing 1 packages: BH
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/4931934/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/BH_1.69.0-1.zip'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  (converted from warning) InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Tempo esaurito per l'operazione'
Error: Failed to install 'plotly' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) download of package ‘BH’ failed

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works! I had to install manually the BH package.